# How to tell headhunters from nice recruiters

Tags: recruitment, negotiation

Any tips on dealing with recruiters that approach me? I really struggle with this especially since i have had a bad experience with a head hunter from a major MNC. How should i avoid being cornered into making a decision before i am satisfied with my demands and perspective?

Comment: Are saying that a headhunter is an evil recruiter?

Comment: kinda ;) sounds a bit scary dont you think ?

Comment: A headhunter is a recruiter that works for the company that has the opening. They are trying to find a person to fill an opening.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep not in all country's in the UK headhunter is some one who works on senior roles and is a cut above the standard recruitment company

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious; it's easy.  Don't make a decision until you're satisfied.

Some recruiters are like used car salesman; high pressure tactics to get you to make a decision.  The reason for that is simple; they get paid when they place you.

However, it's important to recognize that the best leverage in this situation is to just walk away.  Good recruiters will bend over backwards to make sure they're placing the right candidate.  Shady ones will do anything to place *any* candidate.

A couple phrases should do wonders.  Something like:

> I'm sorry, at the current time I'm unable to make a decision on this.  Could you please clarify X, Y, and Z for me?

or

> That sounds good.  Let me sleep on it and I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Good recruiters will understand and work with you.  Those are the guys (and gals) you want to work with.

Comment: yeah i guess it comes with experience. the guy i had the misfortune of dealing with behaved like the used car salesman you describe. even after specifying my exact requirements as to the type of role i wanted, he kept pressurizing me into making a decision and in the end blamed for procrastinating. anyway, thanks for the comments :)